# How to render error messages in views in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a cart in the products view and want to display an error message

views/products/index.html.erb

```
<% if @order.errors.any? %>
  <div class="error error-success note-shadow">
    <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <p><%= msg %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controllers/orders_controller.rb

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params_slip)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.save
      format.html { 
        redirect_to :back,
        notice: 'Order was successfully placed.'
      }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
    end
  end
end
```

I am using the above method trying to display the error messages, but it didn't work out. I supposed that is because my create action is in orders_controller, and I couldn't add the error message to the products view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is the `@order` instance variable is not being carried through the redirection process, so that's the reason you don't see any error messages.
You can put the error messages into `flash` container

```
if @order.save
 [do something]
else
 flash[:order_errors] = @order.errors.full_messages
 redirect_to :back
end

<% if flash[:order_error] %>
 [display it here]
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you put your form in `index.html.erb`. You'd better put your form in your `new.html.erb`.

Try to change:

```
format.html { redirect_to :back }
```

Into:

```
render "index"
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

This will bring the top banner with the error message, then render the "new" page. Usually you would do this as part of controlling your flow. Like if an error has occurred you want to show the user what it is, and take them to a useful page, in my case the page I want to take them to is the "new" page

```rb
flash.now[:error] = @model.errors

render action: "new"
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**